# Google Data Studio - Running Weighted Average (based on % of total relative to corresponding data)

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to create a scorecard to show a 'running' weighted average​​ - that is, depending on the user's selected data from a drop down, it can calculate a weighted average score based on % relative to the corresponding data (i.e. the data selected using the dropdown).

Data Studio (within Tables) allows us to add a comparison calculation with 'Percentage of total * Relative to corresponding data' - which is perfect, since when the user changes the drop down, the comparison calculation is updated based on the corresponding data, and we can see the weight of each row.

However, it doesn't appear to be possible to use the comparison calculation for further metric calculations. To calculate the weighted score, I would need to multiply the Score by the comparison calculation (i.e. the % of Total Orders of the corresponding data) and take the sum of the column.

To give an example (please see [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SlbZrR9CYXOS8qy4IFfzviANQCr8vb9-aZ1jNHoHFGY/edit?usp=sharing) for example base data):

| Month | Country | # Orders | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apr | FR | 1,195 | 67 |
| Apr | DE | 276 | 63 |
| Apr | CH | 788 | 58 |
| Apr | ES | 488 | 69 |
| May | FR | 495 | 62 |
| May | DE | 1,894 | 44 |
| May | CH | 1,496 | 53 |
| May | ES | 1,601 | 53 |
| Jun | FR | 286 | 71 |
| Jun | DE | 275 | 61 |
| Jun | CH | 1,041 | 69 |
| Jun | ES | 1,341 | 60 |
| Jul | FR | 660 | 64 |
| Jul | DE | 1,734 | 55 |

Average Score (non weighted) = 58.75

However, if I want to weight the scores based on the # Orders (i.e. the % of orders relative to corresponding data - which, for the purpose of this question, is left as the base data):

| Month | Country | # Orders | Score | % of Total Orders (to base data) | Individual Weighted Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apr | FR | 1,195 | 67 | 0.07 | 4.97 |
| Apr | DE | 276 | 63 | 0.02 | 1.08 |
| Apr | CH | 788 | 58 | 0.05 | 2.84 |
| Apr | ES | 488 | 69 | 0.03 | 2.09 |
| May | FR | 495 | 62 | 0.03 | 1.90 |
| May | DE | 1,894 | 44 | 0.12 | 5.17 |
| May | CH | 1,496 | 53 | 0.09 | 4.92 |
| May | ES | 1,601 | 53 | 0.10 | 5.27 |
| Jun | FR | 286 | 71 | 0.02 | 1.26 |
| Jun | DE | 275 | 61 | 0.02 | 1.04 |
| Jun | CH | 1,041 | 69 | 0.06 | 4.46 |
| Jun | ES | 1,341 | 60 | 0.08 | 4.99 |
| Jul | FR | 660 | 64 | 0.04 | 2.62 |
| Jul | DE | 1,734 | 55 | 0.11 | 5.92 |
| Jul | CH | 1,267 | 56 | 0.08 | 4.40 |
| Jul | ES | 1,276 | 35 | 0.08 | 2.77 |
|  |  |  |  | Weighted Average Score | 55.71 |

Weighted Average Score = (Sum of Individual Weighted Scores) = 55.71

Q1 - how do I calculate, or create a column in Data Studio, for the " Individual Weighted Score" - i.e. how can we use the comparison calculation to make a new metric / field and calculate each row's weighted score?

Q2 - how do I display the result, i.e. the 'Running' Weighted Average Score, as a single scorecard? (the user doesn't need to see the full table)

Please see here for the [Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/eafae5ff-6fab-4205-8e74-d3cdbcaf505c) example.

Many thanks in advance,

Arran

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [expected output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ds7s6FQbV4Ekiw_aIJshDLbxdY9xyYBgIeHWINhy_X4/edit#gid=454395457) fields can be recreated by first adding a fixed `SUM(# Orders)` field (titled `Total Orders` below), where values in all rows are the total of the `# Orders` field. In Google Data Studio, this currently requires [reaggregation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9429470) through a self [blend](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420) and a cross join:

### 1) Blend Fields

| **Data Source**: | Table 1 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Dimension 1**: | `Month` |  |
| **Dimension 2**: | `Country` |  |
| **Metric 1**: **Aggregation**: **Source Field**: | `# Orders` [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) `# Orders` | `Total Orders` [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) `# Orders` |
| **Metric 1 (Image)**: | [image: blend_calc_1] | [image: blend_Calc_2] |
| **Metric 2**: **Aggregation**: | `Score` [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) |  |
| **Date Range**: | `Month` (Auto) | `Month` (Auto) |
| **Image**: | [image: table_1_blend] | [image: table_2_blend] |

### 2) Join Configuration

| Join Description | Table 1 Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
| **Join Operator**: | Cross |
| **Join Condition**: | Cross joins don't require any conditions |
| **Image**: | [image: join_config] |

### 3) Calculated Fields

| Description | Field 1 | Field 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Name**: **Formula**: **Aggregation**: **Type**: | % of Total Orders (to base data) `# Orders / Total Orders` [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) Numeric > Percent | Individual Weighted Score `(# Orders / Total Orders) * Score` [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) Numeric > Number |
| **Image**: | [image: calc_1_blend] | [image: calc_2_blend] |

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/bf7d8ab1-d839-4bb0-b2bb-c10b50d7492b) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ds7s6FQbV4Ekiw_aIJshDLbxdY9xyYBgIeHWINhy_X4/edit?usp=sharing) data source) to elaborate: